# Adding blog to multiple websites

Tags: seo

My client has multiple products, each with separate websites and would like to start a wordpress based blog.

I would like to somehow connect this blog to each of the product websites so that they can each benefit from the SEO bonuses associated with blogs, if possible.

Ideally each website would have a subdomain blog.example1.com, blog.example2.com etc, which leads to the same blog but where each website example1.com/example2.com gains the SEO benefit.

Not sure if just forwarding these subdomains to the blog page will do the trick, I assume forwarded domains aren't included in the website crawling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you scrap the whole idea and start thinking about the user rather than SEO benefits.

Essentially you're going to have 3 copies of the blog on three different websites. Search engines will come in and index a page on one of the blogs and the others will be seen as duplicates of the first indexed.

Why not have a blog on each site and blog about their respective products. This makes more sense to me.